# How to handle user login with REST API?

Tags: api, rest, backbone.js

I am most definitely doing something wrong, but how am I suppose to validate that the user is in the DB, if I don't have it's ID? I want to verify that he has entered all the good infos and compare those infos with the infos on his account, that I would fetch like that: user/{id}, but I don't have his id. Or maybe the user login has nothing to do with the REST API? I am lost!

EDIT: And I have an Authorization: Basic Auth, but that is maybe more related to the user of the API then the user of the application?

Comment: Is this just an updated version of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624066/am-i-limited-with-a-restful-api-with-backbone)? You should probably delete one of them.

Comment: Yes, I think this one explains my problem better, but maybe i'll get some useful answers on the other question, so i'll wait just a bit before I delete the other one :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to `GET /user/:id` to sign someone into your application, you want something wholly separate for signing in. I'd have a `POST /login` or something similar, send the username and password to that and `/login` can authenticate them and set up the session/cookie/... And, if you want, it could send back the current user's JSON. The result would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/login',
    data: { ... },
    success: function(data) {
        app.current_user = new User(data);
        // etc...
    },
    error: function() {
        // Tell 'em to login properly.
    }
});
```

`app` would be your application's global namespace and `User` would be your client-side user model.

You don't `fetch` the current user, you sign them in and then instantiate them directly from a blob of user data.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you! Heopfuly this is the best way to do it.